# How do you label nodes and create arrows in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I want the nodes to have labels, and the lines to be arrows pointing to the edge of the nodes. And I also want the weight to be on the edges. I am new to D3 and having troubles finding examples to do so. Most of the example graphs are force directed, or creating a directing graph. I wanted to make a kind of a path diagram that is NOT interactive at all.

Basically, I want the source node to point to the target nodes. I just want to draw this graph in d3. I feel like this is really simple, but I just can't seem to figure it out. Any suggestions?

```
<div id="graph">
<script>

var vis = d3.select("#graph")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 1000)
            .attr("height", 1000);

var nodes = [
   {label: "Social Dominance", x: 300, y:400},
   {label: "Gender Identification", x: 500, y: 200},
   {label: "Hostile Sexism", x:500, y:600},
   {label: "Collactive Action", x:700, y:400}

   ], 
    edges =[
   {source: nodes[0], target: nodes[1], weight: 0},
   {source: nodes[0], target: nodes[2], weight: 0},
   {source: nodes[0], target: nodes[3], weight: 0},
   {source: nodes[1], target: nodes[3], weidht: 0},
   {source: nodes[2], target: nodes[3], weight: 0}
   ];

vis.selectAll("circle.nodes")
     .data(nodes)
     .enter()
     .append("svg:circle")
     .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
     .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
     .attr("r", "60px")
     .attr("fill", "pink");


vis.selectAll("line")
    .data(edges)  
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("id", function(d,i){return 'edge'})
    .attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrowhead)')
    .style("stroke", "#ccc");

vis.selectAll(".nodelabel")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr({"cx":function(d){return d.x;},
              "cy":function(d){return d.y;},
              "class":"nodelabel",
              "stroke":"black"})
    .text(function(d){return d.name;});

vis.selectAll(".edgepath")
        .data(edges)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr({'d': function(d) {return 'M '+d.source.x+' '+d.source.y+' L '+ d.target.x +' '+d.target.y},
               'class':'edgepath',
               'fill-opacity':100,
               'stroke-opacity':100,
               'fill':'blue',
               'stroke':'black',
               'id':function(d,i) {return 'edgepath'+i}});

vis.append('defs').append('marker')
    .attr({'id':'arrowhead',
            'viewBox':'-0 -5 10 10',
            'refX':25,
            'refY':0,
        //'markerUnits':'strokeWidth',
            'orient':'auto',
            'markerWidth':100,
            'markerHeight':100,
            'xoverflow':'visible'})
    .append('svg:path')
        .attr('d', 'M 0,-5 L 10 ,0 L 0,5')
        .attr('fill', '#ccc')
        .attr('stroke','#ccc');

</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make some changes in your code. Here is a summary:

1. Texts don't have `cx` or `cy` attributes. They should be `x` and `y`;
2. The text property is `label`, not `name`;
3. You have to set the markers to the `<path>` elements, not to the `<line>` ones;
4. Change the marker attributes to better fit the edge of the circles.

Here is your code with those changes:

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph">
  <script>
    var vis = d3.select("#graph")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", 1000)
      .attr("height", 1000);

    var nodes = [{
        label: "Social Dominance",
        x: 300,
        y: 400
      }, {
        label: "Gender Identification",
        x: 500,
        y: 200
      }, {
        label: "Hostile Sexism",
        x: 500,
        y: 600
      }, {
        label: "Collactive Action",
        x: 700,
        y: 400
      }],
      edges = [{
        source: nodes[0],
        target: nodes[1],
        weight: 0
      }, {
        source: nodes[0],
        target: nodes[2],
        weight: 0
      }, {
        source: nodes[0],
        target: nodes[3],
        weight: 0
      }, {
        source: nodes[1],
        target: nodes[3],
        weidht: 0
      }, {
        source: nodes[2],
        target: nodes[3],
        weight: 0
      }];

    vis.selectAll(".edgepath")
      .data(edges)
      .enter()
      .append('path')
      .attr({
        'd': function(d) {
          return 'M ' + d.source.x + ' ' + d.source.y + ' L ' + d.target.x + ' ' + d.target.y
        },
        'class': 'edgepath',
        'fill-opacity': 100,
        'stroke-opacity': 100,
        'fill': 'blue',
        'stroke': 'black',
        'marker-end': 'url(#arrowhead)',
        'id': function(d, i) {
          return 'edgepath' + i
        }
      });

    vis.selectAll("circle.nodes")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter()
      .append("svg:circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y;
      })
      .attr("r", "60px")
      .attr("fill", "pink");

    vis.selectAll(".nodelabel")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr({
        "x": function(d) {
          return d.x;
        },
        "y": function(d) {
          return d.y;
        },
        "class": "nodelabel",
        "text-anchor": "middle",
        "fill": "black"
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.label;
      });

    vis.append('defs').append('marker')
      .attr({
        'id': 'arrowhead',
        'viewBox': '-0 -5 10 10',
        'refX': 70,
        'refY': 0,
        //'markerUnits':'strokeWidth',
        'orient': 'auto',
        'markerWidth': 10,
        'markerHeight': 10,
        'xoverflow': 'visible'
      })
      .append('svg:path')
      .attr('d', 'M 0,-5 L 10 ,0 L 0,5')
      .attr('fill', '#aaa')
      .attr('stroke', '#aaa');

  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!!  But I have one more question, if I change the nodes from circle to ellipse, how can I make the arrow touch the edge of the ellipse?